# Credenciais em arquivo php

Tags: php, git, deploy, configuração

Quero colocar as credenciais em um arquivo php e irei usar a seguinte solução para deploy em produção:

config.php no ambiente local

```
$username = 'adm';
$senha = 'aaa';
```

1. push para o repositório
2. pull do repositório para o servidor de produção
3. execução de script para substituir adm e aaa pelas credenciais do banco de produção

Minha questão é:

Isso pode ser hackeado de algum jeito e as credenciais serem roubadas?

Comment: se você criar private até tem uma segurança, se for public ai todo mundo vê! Geralmente não se coloca dados sensiveis, que no caso senha é um dado sensível !!!

Answer (score -2):

O `config.php` deve ser declarado no arquivo `.gitignore`, pois dessa forma essas informações sensíveis não ficarão expostas no repositório quando você der o comando `push`. Sugiro que crie um arquivo `config.php.sample` e ao clonar o repositório na máquina de produção, você terá que criar uma cópia do arquivo `config.php.sample` e dar o nome de `config.php` e colocar as credenciais corretas nele.

### Arquivo config.php.sample

```
$username = 'xxx';
$senha = 'xxx';
```

### Arquivo .gitignore

```
/pasta_qualquer
arquivo_qualquer
config.php
```

Comment: ele tem de ficar fora do gitignore pq ele é necessario ao framework. adm e aaa são credenciais de banco local e não sao sensiveis: podem ir p o repositório e serão usadas para fazer o replace na produção pelas credenciais conforme exposto na pergunta.

Comment: Mas mesmo no gitignore o framework conseguirá fazer uso do arquivo, a questão é que quando for feito o clone do repositório no servidor de produção você terá que criar o arquivo e passar as credenciais da base de produção.

Comment: é 1 solução possível tb, pois basta nunca dar push no servidor de produção, o que já não acontece mesmo.

dessa forma o config.php do servidor de produção sempre ficará intacto.

Comment: Por isso mesmo, no servidor de produção vai ser só pull para atualizar e o seu arquivo no gitignore não sofrerá alteração.